# The UILabel is not visible inside the UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Unable to add UILabel inside a UIView programatically in Swift, UIKit

```swift
//
//  GlanceTableViewCell.swift
//
//  Created by Shivacharan Reddy on 23/03/23.
//

import UIKit

class GlanceTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "GlanceTableViewCell"
    
    private let glanceView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private let mainLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .label
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        contentView.addSubview(glanceView)
        
        glanceView.addSubview(mainLabel)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        glanceView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentView.bounds.width - 10).isActive = true
        glanceView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentView.bounds.height - 10).isActive = true
        glanceView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        glanceView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        mainLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: glanceView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: glanceView.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        mainLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: glanceView.bounds.width / 2).isActive = true
        mainLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        
    }
    
}
```

I want to add the `mainLabel` inside `glanceView` which is of type `UIView`, but when I run the code I'm unable to see the `mainLabel`, it is not even visible. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe because you didn't set any text?

Comment: This is not the solution for your problem, but I warmly recommend everyone who is writing UI programmatically to use the pod called `SnapKit`. Very easy to use, makes code more clean and readable.

Comment: @MattiaRighetti I did, it's not in the code above, but even after setting the text I have the same issue.

Comment: Is `glanceView` visible?

Comment: @MattiaRighetti Yes

Comment: I think that the problem is with the `widthAnchor` of `mainLabel`. Can you try to remove it and see what happens? I suspect that `glanceView.bounds.width` is an extremely small value.

Comment: @MattiaRighetti did as you said, but no improvement, mainLabel just doesn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You associate your `glanceView`'s height with `contentView.bound` which is  currently zero

```
glanceView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentView.bounds.height - 10).isActive = true
```

Also glanceView's width is 0 here so label width will be zero and that's because glanceView doesn't know it's width as in your other constraints you don't hook the label leading and trailing to it's bounds in addition it's very early to ask it for it's bounds even if you did set  the mentioned constraints

```
mainLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: glanceView.bounds.width / 2).isActive = true
```

So in  this case you need to asscoiate  it with contentview width

```
mainLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
```

**To Sum up refactor your code to**

```
class GlanceTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let identifier = "GlanceTableViewCell"
    
    private let glanceView: UIView = {
        
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    
    private let mainLabel: UILabel = {
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .label
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        
        contentView.addSubview(glanceView)
        glanceView.addSubview(mainLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            glanceView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            glanceView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            glanceView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            glanceView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            mainLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: glanceView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            mainLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: glanceView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            mainLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            mainLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank You this works, but can you, if possible tell me the issue with my code. You said that my glanceView height is associated with contentView.bound which is 0, but when I run my code I can see the glanceView. Just not the mainLabel.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that, in fact I just changed my mainLabel width anchor code to use multiplier ( `(equalTo: glanceView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)` ) from the original code and it works. Could you explain to me or refer some documentation, so that I can understand this behaviour. 

I'm having a hard time understand why contentView.bound is equal to 0, as you said early on.

Comment: contentView expects it's bounds from your constraints and  since you don't add them properly so it's zero ,  think of conentView as a tent and your constraints as pillars to  stretch  it , so if you  stretched it properly you  can ask it for it's bounds and it will give you a non  zero one